# Change localhost in Express

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm new on express and all of this, so please be kind. After some search I didn't found any answer for my doubt. 
Now I'm using google cloud functions and I want to use express, but for what I understand (not much) i can see what I do just with localhost, there is a way for change the localhost to an specific url (the google function url). From localhost/users to myurl/users. Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you give more details about the task you want to do? Are you talking about how to deploy an app from a URL as a source control? If so, I think this documentation  [https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/deploying/repo ] will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have one cloud function and I want to use express get and post request on this function. On Internet I saw that all the people do that request to localhost, but I need to do that request to my google cloud function url and not to localhost, my question is how I can I do that?

Comment: I'm a little lost. Can you please add some of the examples where people do the request to localhost? Are you following any tutorial?